# Dataverse create view with a filter of today between two date column values

Tags: powerapps, dataverse

I have a table with two date columns (From and To).  I want to filter the records where Today must be on or greater than From and Today must be less than To.

I know I can do this in a PowerApp...

```
Filter(
        'MyTable',
        Today() >= From && Today() < To
    )
```

But can I create a view on the table, and create the filter there, to make my app as low-code as possible?

The filters on a view have operations like Today and On or Before, but nothing like On or Before Today, etc.